# achieving merge cells in table latex

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

How can I achieve this table in latex

[image]

As of now this is the result

[image]

by using this code

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Criteria} & \multirow{2}{*}{Expected} &  \multicolumn{3} 
     {l|}{Actual } & \multirow{2}{*}{Matching Rate} \\ \cline{3-7}
  &  & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 \\ \cline{3-7} \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: this can be achieved via `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`

Comment: how sir im new to latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Criteria}}                                                               & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Expected}}                                 & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Actual}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Matching\\ rate\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{3-7}
        &                                                                    & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trial\\ 1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trial\\ 2\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trial\\ 3\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trial\\ 4\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trial\\ 5\end{tabular}} &                                                                                   \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The device can\\ detect drowsiness\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2 to 3 \\ seconds\end{tabular}} & 2 sec                                                      & 3 sec                                                      & 2 sec                                                      & 2 sec                                                      & 2 sec                                                      & 100\%                                                                             \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|r|}{\textbf{Functionality}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & \textbf{100\%}                                                                    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: can you fix the spacing sir? I'm a little bit confuse to it thanks

Comment: @Raaja I will look into that. And, do you mean the first and second rows?